# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found when loading __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-import

Unable to import pygame into my program

`import pygame`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Can you verify that you have the correct pygame for your python version? Try `pip install pygame`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've mixed a x64 python with x86 pygame file, or vice versa.
Try to uninstall  both your python version and pygame and try downloading it again.

Download python from [Here.](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
Download pygame from [Here.](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml)

## Note

> According to http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml
> NOTE: if you
> had pygame 1.7.1 installed already, please uninstall it first.  Either
> using the uninstall feature - or remove the files:
> c:\python25\lib\site-packages\pygame

## Direct download link for python

Downoad link for python 2.7.11 ===> [Here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/python-2.7.11.msi)

## Direct download link for pygame

Download link for pygame ===> [Here](http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.msi)

**Make sure you install the correct python version and pygame version.Dont mix up the two.**
The links I have provided are **ONLY** for windows and not any other operating system.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12592003)

Comment: I have explained what the user might be doing wrong.And i have provided the download link too to fix the problem.Now i cant do anything else to provide the user the download other than providing them the link. @DhiaTN

Comment: I have already tried the downloads from the sites but the problem persists. Can u please provide dirrect download link for any python and pygame?

Comment: @TimilsinaAashish , Check the edit and confirm , if the problem still persists , tag me in the comment.

Comment: Hi  @TimilsinaAashish if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.